# Session or Cookie [PHP]

Tags: php, session, cookies

I've created a "Recently Viewed Items" script that utilizes sessions to insert viewed products into a database. Then, If there is a session it will pull the products you have viewed.

But, It seems like the sessions 'clear'?

Last night I viewed about 10 products and it was successful but I then proceeded to go to sleep. Once I woke up and tested it again, my session did not exist anymore and it created a new session.

**Edit:** I put my computer to sleep before going to bed last night.

Now, this does not seem optimal but I think I am on the right path to success.

How would you approach this?
Am I utilizing the best resources available to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, sessions have a timeout value. You can see what settings affect this by referring to the [PHP session configuration options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php).

As an alternative, you could store it in cookies or a database. With cookies, you have a limited storage capacity. With the database, you can keep the data attached to the user, but it becomes more difficult to support anonymous users.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me with that script

Comment: So your saying it would be resourceful to use both cookies and sessions

Comment: @RPM you can use a cookie for temporary storage to populate a session, but sessions are more difficult to work with if you're not dealing with a logged in user, unless you have some other way to identify them. While there is the IP, multiple people can come from the same IP, and IP addresses can also be spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched a lot to find an answer but doesn't get anything...and i realize that only my brain could help me and i found a way

set cookies like this

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['recent']))

{$arr = $_COOKIE['recent'];
$arr = $arr." ".$_REQUEST['id'];}
setcookie('recent', $arr, time()+10000, '/');
```

?>
then,

```
$pizza  =$_COOKIE['recent'];
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
$key=0;
foreach ($pieces as $key => $value) {
```

echo here what you want
    }